# create instance of DataColumnChangeEventArgs in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a function as follows:

```
private void Func1(DataColumnChangeEventArgs e)
{
    ds.TableName.AddRow(
        e.Row[e.Column.ColumnName, DataRowVersion.Original].ToString(),
    e.Row[e.Column.ColumnName, DataRowVersion.Proposed].ToString());
}
```

and I am calling it as:

```
private void Func2()
{
    DataColumnChangeEventArgs e = new DataColumnChangeEventArgs(
        dataTable.Rows[index],
        dataTable.Columns["ColName"],
        newValue);

    e.ProposedValue = newValue;
    Func1(e);
}
```

However, `e.Row[e.Column.ColumnName, DataRowVersion.Proposed].ToString()` is throwing a `VersionNotFoundException`. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: It looks like you should be able to do e.Row[e.Column,... instead of e.Column.ColumnName. Not that that's likely to help though.

Comment: Thank you very much JleruOHeP. This completely skipped my mind. It works!! thank you.

Comment: You are welcome! Then I will post it as an answer and I will greatly appreciate, if you check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say, your method should look like this:

```
ds.TableName.AddRow(e.Row[e.Column.ColumnName].ToString(), e.ProposedValue.ToString());
```

As there is no versions in that row in your row in args, but there is new and old values...

Answer (score 0):

DataColumnChangedEventArgs is designed to be used with a class like DataTable. The DataTable creates an instance when calling the associated events (like ColumnChanged). Creating an instance of one will not actually create the change to the data row.

Comment: I do not want to make changes to the DataRow. I wish to access e.Row[e.Column.ColumnName, DataRowVersion.Proposed].ToString()) in Func1(). My question is whether it is achievable through code?

Comment: There is no proposed change to the row. That's what I'm trying to say. Creating a DataColumnChangedEventArgs does not propose a change.

Comment: Ok. Got your point. Thank you very much for looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

The e.ProposedValue = newValue is redundant, you already gave the newValue in the constructor.
You can access the value through e.ProposedValue. So through this system you can only make one change to the row at a time and you must remember which column it was.